# Telerik combobox not rendered properly when twitter's bootstrap applied to project

Tags: telerik-ajax, telerik-radinput

I am developing a project in VS2010 with bootstrap and telerik controls. The only problem it seems to give is that when telerik's radcombobox gets focus, the inputbox inside table of radcombobox does not fit according to the size of a table. An answer on how to change css of combobox to get a desired result will be highly appreciated.

Here is the link to the image - http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/2791/ae01.png

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded latest bootstrap(BS3 RC1) and problem is resolved.